# Simple 2D Collision Detection Algorithm Library

Tags: c++, collision-detection, c

I'm building a simple OpenGL game and I was looking for some simple collision detection library for objects like squares, triangles and circles. Any suggestions?

*PS: Preferably a library that is very well documented and provide examples of 2D collision detections.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Box2D](http://box2d.org/) is very popular and well [documented](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/wiki/FAQ) with lots of examples. Of course it's a full on physics library so it'll give you a good amount of flexibility for expanding later if you want. But you don't need to use those features if you don't want them.

For learning more about the algorithms and how to implement them yourself you can check [this](http://www.gamespp.com/algorithms/collisiondetection/) out.

Additionally [this](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html) is a nice resource for showing how to detect intersections between various shapes. Which plays an important role in collision detection.

Answer (score 4):

I think [box2d](http://box2d.org/) is best 2d physic engine. Which can easily provide collision detection.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically, you could store the position of the objects you want to detect collision with in an array.

then just have a simple Boolean(or even void if the game is simple enough) to detect whether a collision has taken place between the object your checking and your sprite/other object that could be doing the colliding.

ex:

```
int checkCollision()
{
for(int I=0; I<maxObjects; I++)
{
      if(object1_x >= object[I] && object1_x <= object[I] + object[I].width )
      {
           return 1;
      }
  return 0;
}
}
```

this is really messy, but if you want to come up with your own method of detecting collision, you could do something along the lines of that.

I do however recommend using Box2D, much easier.